# Hyperledger: Error trying to ping. Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, networking, deployment, ping, hyperledger

I'm trying to deploy my own .bna file to a business network using 
[this tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org).

The only difference is that I am doing this with three organizations.

Everything works fine until I run the step eight because when I run this command:

```
composer network ping -c alice@trade-network
```

I got this error:

> Error trying to ping. Unexpected end of JSON input.

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to look at the card file? maybe there is something wrong in the card.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I knew it was a matter of local configuration since it stopped working suddenly after throwing several commands. So, I fixed it by stopping fabric and tearing it down.

Then, started fabric, created my peer credential and deployed everything again.

Review the commands in here (section: Controlling your dev environment):
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools.html