# hyperledger composer network ping

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

composer network ping -c admin@tutorial-network

I got this error:

```
Error trying to ping. Unexpected end of JSON input.
```

[Hyperledger: Error trying to ping. Unexpected end of JSON input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144430/hyperledger-error-trying-to-ping-unexpected-end-of-json-input)

The reason for this error is that on the chaincode the identity admin is not activated/registered. There is an error in the output at

> [composerchannel][d72614d6] failed to invoke chaincode name:"tutorial-network" , error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier 'ce733115c6736cd28b4c499f52c28a2f7ed2b8f1a753615907afa1f4551738f0', has not been registered

What is the solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm would guess you are trying to use Composer 0.19.x with a Fabric 1.2 network. Composer 0.19 doesn't support Fabric 1.2, you need to use a Fabric 1.1 network